# Which license inside Power automate allow the service account to run more than 5000 items inside Apply to each

Tags: administration, flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow, licensing

Currently our service account has this free license for power automate, and hence inside any Apply to each we can not process more than 5,000 items:

[image]

So what is the minimum license needed to be able to handle more than 5,000 items inside Apply to each?

Here are the licenses available for us:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apply to each action has limit of 5,000 items for "Low" performance profile and 100,000 for all other performance profiles.

So, you can buy any of the below plans:

[image]

**Source**: [Performance profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#performance-profiles)

Comment: thanks for the info,,, but our license is different we have E1,E2,E3.. now we upgraded the service account to have E3 license is this sufficient ?

Comment: E1, E2, E3 plans comes under "Microsoft 365 plans" which is "Low" performance profile as per above image/documentation & low profiles only supports up to 5000 items.

Comment: ok thanks now inside our company we only grant E1,E2,E3 to the users.. so how i can grant the service account High performance profile? can you advise please?

Comment: Buy any license/plan other than low profiles (as per your requirements) & assign the license to service account. Check [this](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/) & [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-flow-licensing-faq).

Answer (score 1):

A Power Automate per User will give you 5,000 API requests per 24 hours. You can add a Power Automate Capacity Add-on to grant another 10,000 API requests per 24 hours -- this particular license is not assigned to a user.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/api-request-limits-allocations#power-apps-and-power-automate-capacity-add-on

Comment: thanks foe the reply.. my issue is that i am getting all of our Ad users inside Ms flow action (return around 6,000 users), then i am trying to apply a looping on these users.. but i am getting an error that the Apply to Each can only run on max of 5000 items.. so i want to get rid of this error,,, so which license i need to use based on the 2 screen shots i provided?thanks

Comment: can you advice more on your point please? does E3 allow us to handle more than 5000 items inside Apply to Each ?thanks